# Merge two data frames if a list of string matches and list the unmatch string as NA R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, left-join

I have two data frames and I want to assign or paste the string of second data frame in the same row if the string of **Drug_Name** and **Drugz** matches.

**NOTE:**
If I do it by **left_join**  or **merge** `merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE, by.x = "Drug_Names", by.y = "Drugz")`,  it returns me the exact same dataframe that is similar to DF1.

Below is the example of with required DF

DF1

```
>     Pat_ID       Date      Code      Drug_Names
>     AB1     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Alpha
>     AB1     2010-12-15     1.1.1     Alpha
>     AB1     2010-12-15     1.1.1     Beta
>     Ax2     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Beta
>     Ax2     2010-12-17     1.1.1     Beta
>     Aq3     2011-02-09     1.1.1     Gamma
>     Aq3     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Gamma
>     Aw4     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Tango
```

DF2

```
Codez      Drugz
 1.1.1     Alpha
 1.1.3     Gamma
```

Required DF3

> ```
> Pat_ID       Date      Code    Drug_Names    Drugz     Codez
> ```

```
>     AB1     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Alpha      Alpha     1.1.1
>     AB1     2010-12-15     1.1.1     Alpha      Alpha     1.1.1
>     AB1     2010-12-15     1.1.1     Beta        NA         NA
>     Ax2     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Beta        NA         NA
>     Ax2     2010-12-17     1.1.1     Beta        NA         NA
>     Aq3     2011-02-09     1.1.1     Gamma      Gamma      1.1.3
>     Aq3     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Gamma      Gamma      1.1.3
>     Aw4     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Tango       NA         NA
```

Comment: Can you also share the output of `dput` for the data.frames you includes in your example? this is hardly reproducible otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match`.

```
cbind(DF1, DF2[match(DF1$Drug_Names, DF2$Drugz),2:1])
#     Pat_ID       Date  Code Drug_Names Drugz Codez
#1       AB1 2010-12-09 1.1.1      Alpha Alpha 1.1.1
#1.1     AB1 2010-12-15 1.1.1      Alpha Alpha 1.1.1
#NA      AB1 2010-12-15 1.1.1       Beta  <NA>  <NA>
#NA.1    Ax2 2010-12-09 1.1.1       Beta  <NA>  <NA>
#NA.2    Ax2 2010-12-17 1.1.1       Beta  <NA>  <NA>
#2       Aq3 2011-02-09 1.1.1      Gamma Gamma 1.1.3
#2.1     Aq3 2011-04-25 1.1.1      Gamma Gamma 1.1.3
#NA.3    Aw4 2011-04-25 1.1.1      Tango  <NA>  <NA>
```

Or in case using `merge` add the column `Drug_Names` to DF2.

```
merge(DF1, cbind(Drug_Names = DF2$Drugz, DF2), all.x = TRUE)
#  Drug_Names Pat_ID       Date  Code Codez Drugz
#1      Alpha    AB1 2010-12-09 1.1.1 1.1.1 Alpha
#2      Alpha    AB1 2010-12-15 1.1.1 1.1.1 Alpha
#3       Beta    AB1 2010-12-15 1.1.1  <NA>  <NA>
#4       Beta    Ax2 2010-12-09 1.1.1  <NA>  <NA>
#5       Beta    Ax2 2010-12-17 1.1.1  <NA>  <NA>
#6      Gamma    Aq3 2011-02-09 1.1.1 1.1.3 Gamma
#7      Gamma    Aq3 2011-04-25 1.1.1 1.1.3 Gamma
#8      Tango    Aw4 2011-04-25 1.1.1  <NA>  <NA>
```

Data

```
DF1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Pat_ID       Date      Code      Drug_Names
     AB1     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Alpha
     AB1     2010-12-15     1.1.1     Alpha
     AB1     2010-12-15     1.1.1     Beta
     Ax2     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Beta
     Ax2     2010-12-17     1.1.1     Beta
     Aq3     2011-02-09     1.1.1     Gamma
     Aq3     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Gamma
     Aw4     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Tango")

DF2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Codez      Drugz
 1.1.1     Alpha
 1.1.3     Gamma")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Pat_ID       Date      Code      Drug_Names
AB1     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Alpha
AB1     2010-12-15     1.1.1     Alpha
AB1     2010-12-15     1.1.1     Beta
Ax2     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Beta
Ax2     2010-12-17     1.1.1     Beta
Aq3     2011-02-09     1.1.1     Gamma
Aq3     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Gamma
Aw4     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Tango", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  %>%  
as_tibble() %>%
mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))

df2 <- read.table(text = "
Codez      Drugz
 1.1.1     Alpha
 1.1.3     Gamma", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  %>%
as_tibble()
df1  %>%
left_join(df2, by = c("Code" = "Codez", "Drug_Names" = "Drugz"), keep = TRUE)

# A tibble: 8 × 6
  Pat_ID Date       Code  Drug_Names Codez Drugz
  <chr>  <date>     <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>
1 AB1    2010-12-09 1.1.1 Alpha      1.1.1 Alpha
2 AB1    2010-12-15 1.1.1 Alpha      1.1.1 Alpha
3 AB1    2010-12-15 1.1.1 Beta       NA    NA   
4 Ax2    2010-12-09 1.1.1 Beta       NA    NA   
5 Ax2    2010-12-17 1.1.1 Beta       NA    NA   
6 Aq3    2011-02-09 1.1.1 Gamma      NA    NA   
7 Aq3    2011-04-25 1.1.1 Gamma      NA    NA   
8 Aw4    2011-04-25 1.1.1 Tango      NA    NA
```